# If user logged in or not in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

When user logins or when he registers, his `$_SESSION['username']` gets the value of his username. I want to allow them access certain controllers only if they registered. But I don't like the idea of writing this:

```
function __construct()
{
  session_start();
  if(empty($_SESSION['username']))
     die();

  parent::__construct();
}
```

in every controller I don't want unloggined people to see. Is there any better way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider extending your base controller class (see [the Codeigniter Wiki Article on extending the class](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/MY_Controller_-_how_to_extend_the_CI_Controller)) to provide a `require_login` function:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

  protected function require_login() {
    if(empty($_SESSION['username']))
      die();
    }
  }
```

Once you have this, you can call `require_login()` in the constructor of each controller you want to protect:

```
function __construct() {
  $this->require_login();
}
```

Finally, instead of using PHP's `$_SESSION` superglobal for session storage, you might consider taking advantage of the Codeigniter `session` library or [an equivalent](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Native_session).

Comment: Don't forget to call `parent::__construct()`.

Comment: @rjz: The problem is that CI doesn't find MY_Controller. I put it in application/core. `Call to undefined method`

Comment: From the wiki, the controller belongs at `application/libraries/MY_Controller.php`. Just copy it over and you should be golden!

Comment: @rjz: `the 2.x release sees MY_ class extenders relocated to app/core - see the relevant documentation for 2.x.` - I tried it however, still undefined method.

Comment: Oh, now I need to write instead of `extends CI_Controller` to `extends MY_Controller`

Comment: You're right, sorry! Are you remembering to update the controller class itself to extend `MY_Controller` instead of `CI_Controller`?

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but I think I will write a library, so I could call Auth::require_login(), because I don't like idea of extending MY_Controller instead of CI_Controller.

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter has it's [own session, not `$_SESSION`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html).

Apart from that, if you have controller that are of the same type, you can write a base controller and extend from it. The base controller than could contain the code to validate if the controller is accessible and you don't need to write that in each controller class you create. See [*How do I extend the code igniter controller class?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1626305/367456).

Comment: `Codeigniter has it's own session, not $_SESSION.` - they make COOKIE of that, I need session, because then people could just change their username through cookie and login to any account.

Comment: That was just saying. Sometimes questions pop up here and the one who asked was not aware of that. You *can* use `$_SESSION` as this is PHP. Same applies to [`extends`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php).

Comment: There are some reasons you might use native sessions over Codeigniter's `session` library, but @hakre's right--most of CI is written for a reason, and it's good to take advantage of it where you can. Check out http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Native_session for a nice native session wrapper

Answer (score 1):

function __construct()
 {

```
parent::Controller();
$this->authenticate();
```

}

```
function authenticate()
{
   if (!$this->session->userdata('admin_loggedIn'))
  {
  redirect('login');
  }
}
```