# How to call controller from another url with post data?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem with my project using codeigniter.
I want to run some controller from another url(without my project) with post data.
I'm using codeigniter framework?
so have any way to do this?
Please help me resolution this problem...

Comment: Hello, please provide some code so we can understand.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626305/how-do-i-extend-the-code-igniter-controller-class

Comment: I updated my answer, did it work for you  ?

Answer (score 0):

All I can think of is using ajax , but this is not recommended to use javascript as a part of the controller

in controller A

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class controllerA extends CI_Controller {

     function __construct()
    {
        // you can put the ajax call here if you want it to run each time you call this controller
    }

    public function ajaxcall()
    {
    // make sure you didn't call jquery before so you won't have conflicting scripts
    echo '<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"> </script>';

    // now we use ajax to post to the controller B 
    echo
    '<script>
    var target_url = "http://www.example.com/projectB/controllerB"
    var Data = {user_id:542,name:"Baci"};
    $.ajax(
            {
                url : target_url,
                type: "POST",
                data : Data,
                success: function(data)
                {

                    alert("all right request was sent via Ajax  ");

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alert("request failed !  ");
                }
            });
    </script>
    ' ;

    // continue your code on your controller while the ajax call is being sent
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't use any form.